# S3 bucket allows requests from localhost but not 127.0.0.1

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cors, amazon-cloudfront

I have an S3 bucket configured with a CORs policy that allows both http://localhost:8080 and http://127.0.0.1:8080.

I have a basic "fetch" request that looks like:

```
  const response = await fetch(<url-replaced>', {
            method: 'GET',
            mode: 'cors'
        });
  const data = await response.json();
  console.log(data);
```

When I run this code on http://locahost:8080 it runs as expected but if I run it on http://127.0.0.1:8080 I get and error:

`Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://<domain replaced>/data/snap.json. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing). Status code: 200.`

Looking at the Response Headers on the request there's no "access-control-allow-origin" returned on the 127.0.0.1 requests but there are on the localhost requests.

This is my S3 Cross-origin resource sharing (CORS) configuration:

```
[
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [
            "*"
        ],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "GET",
            "HEAD"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "http://localhost:8080",
            "http://127.0.0.1:8080"
        ],
        "ExposeHeaders": [
            "x-amz-server-side-encryption",
            "x-amz-request-id",
            "x-amz-id-2"
        ],
        "MaxAgeSeconds": 3000
    }
]
```